# AndroidStudio, Cloud Firebase data retrieval and display in pie chart issue

Tags: java, android, arrays, google-cloud-firestore

[Cloud Firestore DB structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ocBl.png)I am trying to connect my Android Studio with Google Cloud Firestore to retrieve data but it is showing me that there is No Data in documentSnapshot.exists. From my research, I found that the code has no issue only the structure of the Cloud Firestore has some problem. Can someone please help me resolve this issue by explaining how the data should be structured? I have attached my AndroidStudio code and Cloud Firestore data structure. Really appreciate the help, thank you!

`

```
package com.example.fyp_obv1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.PieChart;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieData;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieDataSet;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.data.PieEntry;
import com.github.mikephil.charting.utils.ColorTemplate;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AssetsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private PieChart pieChart2;
    private ListView listView2;
    private ArrayList<String> liabilitiesList;

    private FirebaseFirestore db;
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.assets_pg);

        // Get references to PieChart and ListView
        pieChart2 = findViewById(R.id.pieChart);
        listView2 = findViewById(R.id.assetsListView);

        db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUser = auth.getCurrentUser();

        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid(); // Retrieve the user identifier

            // Fetch asset document ID from Firestore
            db.collection("users")
                    .document(userId)
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot -> {
                        if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                            String assetDocumentId = documentSnapshot.getString("assetDocumentId");

                            // Fetch asset data from Firestore
                            db.collection("users")
                                    .document(userId)
                                    .collection("assets")
                                    .document(assetDocumentId)
                                    .get()
                                    .addOnSuccessListener(documentSnapshot1 -> {
                                        if (documentSnapshot1.exists()) {
                                            Assets asset = documentSnapshot1.toObject(Assets.class);

                                            // Process the retrieved asset data
                                            ArrayList<PieEntry> pieEntries = new ArrayList<>();
                                            liabilitiesList = new ArrayList<>();

                                            pieEntries.add(new PieEntry((float) asset.getValue(), asset.getName()));
                                            liabilitiesList.add(asset.getName() + ": RM " + asset.getValue());

                                            // Set up PieChart data
                                            PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(pieEntries, "Assets");
                                            dataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.COLORFUL_COLORS);
                                            PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);

                                            pieChart2.setData(data);
                                            pieChart2.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
                                            pieChart2.invalidate();

                                            // Set up ListView data
                                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, liabilitiesList);
                                            listView2.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        } else {
                                            Toast.makeText(AssetsActivity.this, "No Data exist in documentSnapshot1.exists()!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        }
                                    })
                                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                                        Toast.makeText(AssetsActivity.this, "Firestore Not Available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    });
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(AssetsActivity.this, "No Data in documentSnapshot.exists()!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Toast.makeText(AssetsActivity.this, "Cant fetch data!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AssetsActivity.this, "User not logged in! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
[Cloud Firestore Data Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3juo.png)
```

I am expecting the data to be displayed in a pie chart and list format which is to be fetched from Cloud Firestore and displayed in the Android application

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Done with the edit, its at the top of the question listed as "Cloud Firestore DB structure". Hope it helps!

Comment: Inside onSuccess are you getting the desired data?

Comment: From what I understand, the code does not work after if (documentSnapshot.exists()) {| this line because it goes to the else statement and executes it. Can I know if the data structure in Cloud Firebase is structured correctly?

Comment: So you say that the `documentSnapshot` doesn't exist, right? Besides that, is your goal to get all assets documents of all users?

Comment: Yes, that's the error message that I'm getting from my if...else statements, meaning there is an issue in the first documentSnapshot if statement. Also when I replace the userId and assetDocumentId with the real ID's from Cloud Firestore I'm getting the error message User not logged in. Can I know how do I fix this problem? Should I use Realtime Database and migrate to that to get easier access to the data?

To answer your question, yes, my goal is to get assets for specific user as different users will have different assets in different documents, hence the code as such